# Is it possible to customize WPF view creating mechanism to use my own ViewFactory?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, extensibility

I can create views myself using IoC without any problems if all dependencies that my view constructor needs as arguments are registered within my IoC-container.

But in case if I try to extensively use DataTemplates, then WPF creates my views. And in case if view has no default constructor, then WPF will fail and crash whole app. Thus my question is - are there any extensibility points in WPF so that I can provide a view factory to it, which will be able to create my views even when they do not have default constructor?

Comment: what kind of IoC container you are using? I suggest Prism for that.

Comment: I am using Prism, but it is not an IoC container, as far as I know. And as an IoC I use Autofac. As I said - I need to know about WPF extensibility points so that I can provide WPF with my own (IoC based) view factory.

Comment: Prism library includes the UnityBootstrapper which implement functionality necessary to use Unity as ioc container. You may use the same for writing your own factory for resolving the types.

Comment: I do not think you understand me. I have IoC containter, and it work fine for me. But there are cases when WPF itself (not me) is creating views. And in this case if a view does not have a default constructor - WPF throws an exception. What I want - is to give WPF a class, that will be able to use IoC container to create views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, and to my knowledge, the answer is no. I was just looking for the same thing, but WPF can only create user controls with parameterless constructors.

One solution would be to use the Service Locator pattern, where your UserControl has access to the container in its constructor and Resolves its dependency by itsself. I personally don't like this pattern. Some call Service Locator an anti-pattern, and in the long run, it can get you into trouble.

Comment: I agree, I have not found anything for this since posting.